# (SQLite) ¿Por qué no se crea la base de datos?

Tags: android, sqlite

Tengo un programa que guarda en una tabla unos usuario que yo inserto, pero cuando ejecuto la app, me dice que la tabla no existe. He creado un toast para comprobarlo y ni siquiera se muestra. Este es el código de la clase que trata la base de datos:

```
public class DBAccess extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Nombre de la base de datos
    private static final String DB_NAME = "dc_usuarios";
    //Nombre de la tabla
    private static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "usuarios";
    // Versión
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
    //Columnas
    private static final String USER_COLUMN = "nombreUsuario";
    private static final String PASSWORD_COLUMN = "contra";

    private Context mContext;

    public DBAccess(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;

    }

    // onCreate crea la base de datos y las tablas. Hay que sobrecargarlo.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // Creamos y lanzamos la consulta para crear la/s tablas de nuestra DB. El metodo onCreate se llama exclusivamente si la
        // base de datos no existe.
        String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +DB_TABLE_NAME + "(" +USER_COLUMN + " TEXT," +PASSWORD_COLUMN+ " TEXT)";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Tabla creada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // onUpgrade actualiza la base de datos y las tablas asociadas.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int i1) {
        /*switch(oldVersion){
            case 1:
                //sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE" + DB_TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + POBLATION_COLUMN + "INTEGER");
            case 2:
                //sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TALBE" + DB_TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + SURFACE_COLUMN + "REAL");
            case 3:
                //sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE ciudades ADD COLUMN gentilicio TEXT");
                break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Base de datos actualizada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
    }

    public void insertarUsuario(String usuario, String contrasenia){
        // Pedimos acceso de escritura en la BD
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(USER_COLUMN, usuario);
        values.put(PASSWORD_COLUMN, contrasenia);

        // Insertamos a través del método insert los valores asociados al contenedor values
        long result = db.insert(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        // Comprobación de errores
        if(result != -1){
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Usuario insertado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        db.close();
    }
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Elimina el caché de la aplicación para que cree nuevamente la Base de datos y su estructura con la tabla que deseas crear @pacopepe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**La base de datos seguramente esta creada, lo que no se crea es la tabla.**

Tienes dos opciones:

- Elimina el caché de la aplicación.
- Desinstala e instala la aplicación nuevamente.

hay otra opción

- Cambia la versión de la base de datos  `private static final int DB_VERSION = 3;`

pero necesitarías agregar la tabla dentro de `onUpgrade()` :

```
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int i1) {
  ...
}
```

---

La razón de tu problema es que seguramente se creo la base de datos con una estructura que no contenía la tabla, pero como no se vuelve a llamar nuevamente `onCreate()` ya que la aplicación lo realizo, entonces no se crea la nueva estructura.

Comment: Ha funcionado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hey que bien PacoPepe, en el sitio había una pregunta un poco similar a esta pero no la encontré, tal vez fue eliminada, me da gusto funciono  saludos!